# wxWidgets ribbonBar taking up entire window

Tags: c++, visual-c++, wxwidgets

I've spent the past day figuring out how to get a wxRibbon bar. It took some work, but I finally got a ribbon bar working. Except that the ribbon bar takes up the entire window, except for a tiny space on the right side of my application.

The code I'm using to test in my main window is as follow:

```
Win_app::Win_app(const wxString& title)
       : wxFrame(NULL, wxID_ANY, title, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(640, 480))
{

    wxRibbonBar* mainMenu = new wxRibbonBar(this,-1,wxDefaultPosition,wxSize(20,40));


    wxRibbonPage* home = new wxRibbonPage(mainMenu, wxID_ANY, wxT("Home"));

    wxRibbonPanel *test_panel1 = new wxRibbonPanel(home, wxID_ANY, wxT("Panel 1"), 
                                            wxNullBitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(320,60));

    wxRibbonPanel *test_panel2 = new wxRibbonPanel(home, wxID_ANY, wxT("Panel 2"), 
                                            wxNullBitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(320,60));

    wxRibbonPage* page = new wxRibbonPage(mainMenu, wxID_ANY, wxT("Another Page"));

    wxRibbonPanel *test_panel3 = new wxRibbonPanel(page, wxID_ANY, wxT("Panel 3"), 
                                            wxNullBitmap, wxDefaultPosition, wxSize(640,60));


    mainMenu->Realize();


    Centre();
}
```

I'm using wxWidgets 2.9.4. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest taking a look at the ribbon sample in your wxWidgets install located at `wxdir\samples\ribbon`. It looks to be doing roughly the same as your code with a key difference in that it adds the wxRibbonBar to a sizer:

```
wxSizer *s = new wxBoxSizer(wxVERTICAL);

s->Add(m_ribbon, 0, wxEXPAND);
s->Add(m_logwindow, 1, wxEXPAND);
s->Add(m_togglePanels, wxSizerFlags().Border());

SetSizer(s);
```

You need to do this because if there is a single control on a dialog it automatically fills the dialog, which in your case is unwanted behaviour.

Comment: Sweet. :D That did it. I didn't see that part in the sample code I was using. Thank you so much, now I can move on with the rest of the program.